# XAML Multibinding Path not working inside BindableLayout

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am trying to use a multi-binding inside of a BindableLayout and I can't get the "Answer" binding to scope correctly.

This line:                                 `<Binding Path="SelectedAnswers" Source="{x:Reference this}" />` is working correctly and is passed into the converter.

This line: `<Binding Path="Answer" Source="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />` is just null;

You can see on the Button text property I am using "Answer" there too and it is not null.

```
<FlexLayout Wrap="Wrap" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentQuestion.SurveyQuestionAnswers}">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:SurveyQuestionAnswerViewModelRead">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Button Text="{Binding Answer}" Command="{Binding QuestionAnsweredCommand, Source={x:Reference this}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" >
    
                        <Button.IsVisible>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ListAnyMultiValueConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="SelectedAnswers" Source="{x:Reference this}" />
                                <Binding Path="Answer" Source="{RelativeSource Mode=Self}" />
    
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </Button.IsVisible>
                    </Button>
                </StackLayout>
    
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </FlexLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is a misunderstanding of `{RelativeSource Mode=Self}`. That is looking for a property `Answer` **on the Button** element. There is no such property of course.

(You could use this mode to refer to `Text` property of button. But might as well bind directly to the same variable that Text does.)

Do:
`<Binding Path="Answer"/>`

That will look in the `BindingContext`, just like `{Binding Answer}` did on Button Text.